# What DHCP option tags are used by standards but not recorded?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, autodiscovery

I've been working on setting up an in-house service that uses DHCP to let clients auto-discover the server's location. I took a look at [IANA's BOOTP and DHCP option tags](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml) to see what's available to use, and I noticed, down at the end, that options 224-254 are marked as "Reserved (Private Use)", so I decided to use options 251, 252, 253, and 254 to provide the clients with what they need to discover and register with the service. I figured this was the way to go because we also set up the Wyse Management Suite's autodiscovery to use DHCP.

I made the mistake of putting the URL of the service in DHCP option tag 252. The next day, every machine stopped connecting to the web, since it was trying to use the URL in option tag 252 as a web proxy, according to the [Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol). I quickly took it out, they stopped trying to connect through the "proxy", and everyone was happy.

So, before I make this mistake again, which DHCP option tags are used by known services, such as WPAD, but not actually recorded by IANA, that I will have to worry about?

Comment: Probably none. WPAD dates back to the time when Microsoft was busy trying to conquer the Internet by deliberately doing everything as nonstandard as they could and then forcing it on everyone. Most such things failed in the end, fortunately. WPAD never got past Internet-Draft or it probably would have gotten a real option number, 252 having been a placeholder. But even though it failed to reach RFC status it was so widely deployed already that it would have been impossible to change anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the option tags 224, 225, 226, and 227 instead then and see if they break anything.